# not found symbol error when trying to generate code using open api

Tags: spring-boot, openapi-generator

I'm trying to use open api 3 with spring boot 2. It generates ApiUtil class. I'm using use JAVA 11.
but it could not find this class when building the project.

```
[ERROR] /Users/bilelfrikha/Documents/clothes-api-many/clothes-api-interface/target/generated-sources/openapi/{project.build.directory}/generated-sources/swagger/src/gen/java/org/example/clothes/api/v1/ClothesApi.java:[175,21] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ApiUtil
  location: interface org.example.clothes.api.v1.ClothesApi
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>
                          ${basedir}/src/main/resources/clothes-api/clothes.yaml
                        </inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <apiPackage>org.example.clothes.api.v1</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>org.example.clothes.api.v1.dto</modelPackage>
                        <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                        <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:8080/v1/clothes-api-docs</apiDocsUrl>
                        <outputFileName>openapi.json</outputFileName>
                        <outputDir>${project.build.directory}</outputDir>
                        <configOptions>
                            <library>spring-boot</library>
                            <sourceFolder>{project.build.directory}/generated-sources/swagger/src/gen/java</sourceFolder>
                            <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but were you able to figure out what the issue was?